# My Google Drive app showing very old icon, but only on Chromebook all apps page

Tags: google-drive-api, google-chrome-os

I have made a drive app, added to drive through permissions. It is not published in the Chrome web store, but is picked up by my chromebook as an app.

The app shows the same icons, as specified in the developers console, wherever I see them, except, I now discover, on my chromebook. Clicking on the finder brings up an icon I haven't used in several months. It may have been specified at some point in the old console, which appears now to be completely unreachable.

When I look at App info, it shows the correct icon.

So, question is, where is Chrome OS / Chromebook / Google getting this icon from, and how can I remove/delete/update it?

Comment: Why the down vote? It's a valid SDK question.

Answer (score 0):

When you published you app in Chrome, you have supplied some images.. you can review the images and see if you can find this old icon there..
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#create-your-apps-zip-file

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my question, I didn't publish it in Chrome. It's picking up the app which is a drive app, added through drive permissions.